# Jquery Drop down content panel

Tags: jquery, panel, slide, hoverintent

Could anyone give me some help with this please? The content needs to appear after hovering over a second (I tried using hoverIntent but I couldn't get it to work) and it needs to stay open, only closing/sliding back up when the button is clicked.

Here it is on jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VDcL4/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDcL4/5/)

```
$(".btn-slide").on('mouseenter click', function(e) {
    switch(e.type) {
        case 'mouseenter':
            $("#panel").stop().slideDown("slow");
            break;
        case 'click':
            $("#panel").stop().slideUp("slow");
            break;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Your welcome :). Like Mukesh said, check the correct answer as accepted so others who may be in the same situation get a fast solution.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is replace slideToggle slideDown() -

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-slide").hover(function() {
        $('#panel').slideDown(1000);
        $(this).addClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Why did you use slideToggle in the first place?

Comment: thank you so much! Works great. I'm new to jquery so I was copying from someone elses script :)

Comment: @user1439038 Glad i could help. Can you please accept the answer as the correct one